# sqlite3: Error: unknown command or invalid arguments: "once"

Tags: command-line, sqlite

According to the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) this is how you can export a table to .csv:

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .once c:/work/dataout.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1;
sqlite> .system c:/work/dataout.csv
```

However, on line 3 of this sequence of commands I get:

```
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "once". Enter ".help" for help
```

My path is valid, I have permission to write to that location. My sqlite3 version is

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30 27392118af4c38c5203a04b8013e1afdb1cebd0d
```

running on Ubuntu 14.04

I have googled for this error message, nothing useful on it this far.

---

FIX:

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output dataout.csv 
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1
```

should work for the current version. Otherwise update to a newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `once` command was added in SQLite version 3.8.5 based on the [changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) so it doesn't exist in your system. If you really need it you might be able to upgrade your version to a newer one.

If you don't want to / can't upgrade you can use the `output` command and just run one SQL command after it to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The `.once` command in the SQLite 3 shell is from [version 3.8.5, circa June 2014](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_5). Your version is from before this command was introduced, hence the "unknown command" error.

Either find an up-to-date SQLite package, or compile and install SQLite from source.

Comment: OK, I have just realised this by checking the rest of the page.